# Open iOS app with an URL

Tags: objective-c, ios, url-scheme

I'm trying to set URL Scheme for my app. I read this [tutorial](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html) and it works perfectly when I call `myapp://test` from an other app or from Safari app and Mail app (iOS native apps).
But how can I do in order to open my app from an other app (Chrome, Gmail, etc...) ?

Thanks.

Comment: So do you want other apps to detect your app and put it in the "open in..." list?

Comment: No, when I click on the URL in Gmail app or when I go to an URL on Chrome (if the url contains myapp://test), it's open my app. I just want the same behaviour than the Safari and Mail iOS native apps. Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: If there is no way, please add an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I think when you click on a link that points to your app, it will be opened, whatever app you are navigating in.

Comment: @H2CO3 : I can affirm that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's seems to be not possible. It's just possible with the iOS native apps for the moment :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some other third part app could not support unknown scheme such as your self-defined url. But if it support `http` scheme, you could do it. You could make a url link whois scheme is 'http'. And this url wrapped your self-defined url like `myapp://test`. You could make the http url link redirect to your self-defined url link.

Comment: How to do that? Can you please give an example

Answer (score -2):

You can set a secret key like `myapp://test`. You can do this under your project settings -> URL type. In there you need to define your secret key. When entering this key into your safari browser your app is being opened automaticly.

Comment: he said he has it working, it is just that some apps like Chrome don't follow non-http links.